# List Search Optimization

Tags: python, optimization

```
first = [(1, text, text, 1, 2, 3), 
         (1, text, text, 1, 0, 3), ... (6054, text, text, 2, 2, 3)]
second = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 5412)
```

Is there a faster way to do this:

```
data = [x for x in first if x[0] in second]
```

Comment: Its not at all clear what you're trying to do. From what I can see all the elementds in first will be selected

Comment: @Falmarri - edited to make things clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
first = [(1, text, text, 1, 2, 3), 
         (1, text, text, 1, 0, 3), ... (1054, text, text, 2, 2, 3)]
second = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 5412)
second_set = set(second)
data = [x for x in first if x[0] in second_set]
```

Assume first has m elements and second has n elements.

Sets are hashed, so searching them is close to O(1) giving an overall efficiency of O(m).  Searching second as a list is O(n) giving an overall efficiency of O(m * n).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want just this instead of the `in` check:

```
data = [x for x in first if 1 <= x[0] <= 5412 ]
```

Comment: Thanks. But Jason Baker's answer is what I was looking for. (I have used a very simple example in my question but what if the second list has other data types?)